# Horizontal scrolling images inside recyclerview

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, viewpagerindicator

I have to make a scrolling images inside a recycler view with dot as indicator. Please have a look at attached screenshot for the same. Circled image is the dot indicator.

[image]

So far i have used the RecyclerView and using the GridLayoutManager. Inside Adapter i have made another item which is HEADER_TYPE i.e for scrolling images. For scrolling i am using [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator) library and have successfully imported to my project.

As i am new to android i am not able to move further i do not have any idea how can i use this inside my project.

Also please suggest whether its the right path to achieve the same result or suggest some another way of doing the same.

My code so far:

```
 public static final int TYPE_HEADER = 1;
public static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;


List<CatetoryListModel> data = Collections.emptyList();
LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;

public CategoryRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<CatetoryListModel> data) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_header, parent, false);
        MyViewHolderHeader myViewHolder = new MyViewHolderHeader(view, context);
        return myViewHolder;

    } else {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_custom_row, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view, context);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

}

@Override
// public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
    //  layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
    if (holder instanceof MyViewHolder) {
        CatetoryListModel current = data.get(position - 1);  //potion now becomes 1 and data start from 0 index
        //holder.title.setText(current.getCategoryName());
        // holder.desp.setText(current.getDescription());
        ((MyViewHolder) holder).icon.setImageResource(current.getImgSrc());
    } else {
       // ((MyViewHolderHeader) holder).icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.banner);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0)
        return TYPE_HEADER;

    return TYPE_ITEM;
}

//Returns the total number of items in the data set hold by the adapter.
//no of items to be rendered by adapter
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size() + 1;
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView title;
    TextView desp;
    ImageView icon;
    Context cntxt;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView, Context c) {
        super(itemView);

            cntxt = c;
            itemView.setClickable(true);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            // title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.category);
            //  desp = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgsrc);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(cntxt, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

class MyViewHolderHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    //ImageView icon;
   // ViewPager mPager;
  //  CirclePageIndicator mIndicator;
  //  TestFragmentAdapter mAdapter;

    public MyViewHolderHeader(View itemView, Context c) {
        super(itemView);

     //   mAdapter = new TestFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

     //   mPager = (ViewPager)itemView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
      //  mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

      //  mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)itemView.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
      //  mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);

    }

}
```

recycler_header.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />
```

recycler_custom_row.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imgsrc"
    android:src="@drawable/close" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you found any solution for this???

Comment: how to design this layout am also looking that please give some ideas and help

Comment: when coordinate layout if any of the options menu icon is clicked the toolbar title text is invisible please help me to display title on tool bar alsways fixed.